Why is the group list empty even though this contact is a member of a group?
I have grouped the contacts, but when I run the print() command in the console, the list of groups is empty.
Why is the group list empty even though this contact is a member of a group?

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/contact.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContactsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ContactsPage> createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {
  List<Contact> _contacts =[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchContacts();
  }

  Future _fetchContacts() async {
    if (!await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
    } else {
      List<Contact> contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(withProperties: true);
      setState(() => _contacts = contacts);
      print(_contacts);
    }
    return _contacts;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _fetchContacts(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _contacts.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(_contacts[index].groups[0].name),
              );
            }, );
        },),
    );
  }
}

console result:
I/flutter ( 9205): [Contact(id=253, displayName=A. H pahlozadeh, thumbnail=null, photo=null, isStarred=false, name=Name(first=A., last=pahlozadeh, middle=H, prefix=, suffix=, nickname=, firstPhonetic=, lastPhonetic=, middlePhonetic=), phones=[], emails=[Email(address=ahamidp@gmail.com, label=EmailLabel.other, customLabel=, isPrimary=true)], addresses=[], organizations=[], websites=[Website(url=http://www.google.com/profiles/114734360510822226117, label=WebsiteLabel.profile, customLabel=)], socialMedias=[], events=[], notes=[], accounts=[], groups=[]


By your log, you can notice that all of the properties regarding your contact are missing:
I/flutter ( 9205): [Contact(id=253, displayName=A. H pahlozadeh, thumbnail=null, photo=null, isStarred=true, name=Name(first=, last=, middle=, prefix=, suffix=, nickname=, firstPhonetic=, lastPhonetic=, middlePhonetic=), phones=[], emails=[], addresses=[], organizations=[], websites=[], socialMedias=[], events=[], notes=[], accounts=[], groups=[])

That is because when you request contacts through the FlutterContacts API, you didn't add the argument to get the properties nor the one for groups.
To do so, you can do this:
Future _fetchContacts() async {
    if (!await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
    } else {
      List<Contact> contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(
  withProperties: true, withGroups: true); /// <---- HERE
      setState(() => _contacts = contacts);
      print(_contacts);
    }
    return _contacts;
  }

You can also see this in the example of the package in pub.dev.
Reference

By adding "withProperties: true" the rest of the properties are filled except for groups. where is the problem?

@Ehsanzarei - I have updated the answer. You need to pass the argument withGroups: true.

Thank you very much @tomerpacific. Please help me in solving this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79082867/why-does-the-group-fieldlabel-remain-empty-when-i-insert-a-new-contact

if you change your code like this everythings will be ok
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/contact.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContactsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ContactsPage> createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {
  List<Contact> _contacts =[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchContacts();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchContacts() async {
    if (!await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
    } else {
      List<Contact> contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(withProperties: true);
      setState(() { _contacts = contacts; print(_contacts);});
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _contacts.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(_contacts[index].groups[0].name),
              );
            })
    );
  }
}


It doesn't work for me..thanks for reply M.Fazel
