Why does the group field(label) remain empty when I insert a new contact?
I want to add a new contact and specify the group argument. With this piece of code and according to the result of the print() command, everything seems correct, but when I refer to the created contact, I notice that the field group (label) is empty.
Edit: The lib folder of my project has two files. main.dart and insert_contact.dart.When I build the project, it is expected that the new contact will be added to the contacts in the emulator and the group name will be displayed in the label field.
main.dart file:
import 'package:myapp/insert_contact.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: InsertContact(),
    );
  }
}

inset_contact.dart file:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/contact.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';

class InsertContact extends StatefulWidget {
  const InsertContact({super.key});

  @override
  State<InsertContact> createState() => _InsertContactState();
}

class _InsertContactState extends State<InsertContact> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _insertContact();
  }

  Future<void> _insertContact() async {
    if (!await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
    } else {
      final newContact = Contact()
        ..displayName ='Ehsan Zarei'
        ..name.first = 'Ehsan'
        ..name.last = 'Zarei'
        ..phones = [Phone('123456789')]
        ..groups= [Group('444', 'Edu')];
      await newContact.insert();
      print(newContact);
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

console result:
I/flutter ( 7976): Contact(id=, displayName=Ehsan Zarei, thumbnail=null, photo=null, isStarred=false, name=Name(first=Ehsan, last=Zarei, middle=, prefix=, suffix=, nickname=, firstPhonetic=, lastPhonetic=, middlePhonetic=), phones=[Phone(number=123456789, normalizedNumber=, label=PhoneLabel.mobile, customLabel=, isPrimary=false)], emails=[], addresses=[], organizations=[], websites=[], socialMedias=[], events=[], notes=[], accounts=[], groups=[Group(id=444, name=Edu)])

result in emulator:

After that, I open the contacts application and expect that a new contact has been created with these specifications:

I open the contacts application and see the newly created contact.The details are correctly stored in the relevant fields:

But the label field, which is related to the group argument, is empty:


Where is the logic to get the contacts after you add a contact? How do you pull the contacts? Do you include the withProperties and withGroups arguments?

Please provide us the code which you build the contact form

dear @tomerpacific, The lib folder of my project has two files. main.dart and insert_contact.dart.When I build the project, it is expected that the new contact will be added to the contacts in the emulator and the group name will be displayed in the label field.

dear @saman, I edited the question now.

@Ehsanzarei - When is the contact inserted and when are you pulling the contacts?

@tomerpacific , I edited my question and explained more.
